# Why doesn't corebuild work with absolute paths?

Tags: ocaml

I was using `ocamlc.opt` like this:

```
ocamlc.opt -I /home/foo/bar/baz -c foo.ml
```

I thought I could do the same with `corebuild`:

```
ocamlc.opt -I /home/foo/bar/baz -c foo.ml
```

But that throws an error:

```
Failure:
  Included or excluded directories must be implicit (not "/home/foo/bar/baz").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR, `corebuild` does some internal directory re-ordering and explicit paths break its re-ordering algorithm.

Comment: what's the fix?

Comment: @JessBowers: avoid using explicit includes, [ref](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#module-paths-and-include-directories).